# Avaya Communicator web is not working

Tags: oauth2, oauth, servicecloud, login-errors, remote-access

We use Avaya communicator web to run our call center. When I open Avaya web extension (Google chrome) and click on login through Salesforce credential and login. I got an error message:
“License information cannot validate” 
When I checked login history so its show success through remote access2.0 through Avaya communicator and also OAuth shows count 1. I have changed profile permission for Cx team gave them Admin profile but still the same error message displayed.
When I tried with my credential its working fine. I have contacted Avaya support then they said it’s a Salesforce issue.
Could you please help me to figure out the issue?

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: Wow, that's some bad support from Avaya! I don't know how well Avaya's solution integrates with Salesforce, but is your Cx team assigned to a call centre? What about your user?

Comment: Yes, they all are added in call center. And have service cloud checked.